# php code to update sort order according to category

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

news(id,cat_id,headline,sub_top_priority)
I create **drag and drop sortable list.**

**It change the sub_top_priority column order in database.**

**But i need this to change order of sub_top_priority column according to category.**

for example.
Database has 6 rows

id         cat_id            headline          sub_top_priority
1            15               good                   1
2            15               Bad                    2
3            15               Nice                   3
4            15               Fine                   1
5            16               Test1                  2
6            16               Test2                  3

if I Drag the second row and drop on first row then it only change order of category = 15 not of category = 16. category 16  sub_top_priority column remains as it is.

plz help me to make update and plz suggest what should i change in code...to update sub_top_priority column order according to cat_id.

I Try to change id with cat_id but this change all category in same sequence.

```
 <?php   
                    while ($sub_top = mysql_fetch_array($sub_top_select)) 
                    {
                    ?>      
                <li id="recordsArray1_<?php echo $sub_top['id']; ?>">&nbsp;<?php echo $sub_top['category_name']; ?> : <?php echo $sub_top['headline']; ?></li>
                <?php } ?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['change']))
    {   
        $change = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['change']); 
        $updateRecordsArray1 = $_POST['recordsArray1'];
        if ($change == "updatesubtop")
        {           
            $listingCounter1 = 1;
            foreach ($updateRecordsArray1 as $recordIDValue1)
            {       
                $query1 = "UPDATE news SET sub_top_priority = " . $listingCounter1 . " WHERE id = " . $recordIDValue1;              
                mysql_query($query1) or die($query1."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
                $listingCounter1 = $listingCounter1 + 1;
            }           

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: After drag & drop on Javascript (probably) create a loop and specify the order (showed) you want, pass that data to PHP and do your query update.

Comment: i create update query but this is not update rows according to category id.this updates according to id .I need this to update row according to their category.

Comment: Id,cat_id,headline,sub_top_priority

Comment: do not update WHERE id but WHERE cat_id maybe will help =)